# Basic Python range and slicing not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, slice

Can someone explain what happened here?
The slicing seems to be off isn't it?
doing this on the interactive shell.

```
>>> range(3,100,7)[0:5]
range(3, 38, 7)
```

Comment: What outputs are you getting that you think are wrong?

Comment: `38` is not part of the range defined by `range(3,38,7)`, if that is what you are wondering about.

Comment: You didn't specify what you expected to happen instead, so people are *guessing* at what you wanted the output to be in the answers. Please include the desired behavior in your question.

Answer (score 3):

`range(3, 100, 7)` returns a `range` object. That `range` object understands slicing.  Note that `list(range(3,100,7))[0:5]` is the same as `list(range(3,38,7))`

Answer (score 2):

Since python3 `range()` outputs it's own type, and understands slicing :

```
>>> range(100)[5:10]
range(5, 10)
```

You must convert it to a list if you want to use it as such :

```
>>> list(range(100))[5:10]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So this would also work, and is probably better in terms of performance :

```
list(range(100)[5:10])
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Maaaaan, i was almost finished with the answer that covers part of firstly slicing `range()` object and then converting it to `list`. Good catch!